# Laravel 5.5 : MongoDB & hasManyThrough() relation

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel-5.5

I use **MongoDB with Laravel**: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

I have two tables (*feeds, users*) and a collection on MongoDB (*articles*) that come in this form:

> articles (MongoDB):
>
> - _id (ObjectID)
> - feed_id
> - title
>
> feeds (MySQL):
>
> - id
> - user_id
> - name
>
> users (MySQL):
>
> - id
> - name

I would like to retrieve all the articles of a user while passing by "feeds".

For this, I use the hasManyThrough() relation in the User model:

```
public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Article::class,
            Feed::class,
            'user_id',
            'feed_id',
            '_id',
            'id'
        );
    }
```

But the problem is that on each user, I have the same articles listed, it looks like it does not take into account user_id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package not supporting 
`$this->hasManyThrough` - relation .

Relations Supported relations are:

1. hasOne
2. hasMany
3. belongsTo
4. belongsToMany
5. embedsOne
6. embedsMany

You can check documentation :
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb